# Nested Mixin in Jade causes Illegal Token Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, mixins

I have a complicated Jade template, which I simplified for this question. I'm looking at having dynamic nested mixin that changes attributes of an input based on the value of a string that I pass through. I have to use the mixin for the input, so not having that isn't an option for me unfortunately. I get the error `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` on the line with `+input_mixin(...`.

```
mixin name_of_mixin(type)
    - if type == 'multiple'
        - var name = '{{:#index}}'
    - else if type == 'old'
        - var name = 'old'
    - else
        - var name = 'normal'
    +input_mixin(#{name})
```

Comment: I am really not an expert when it comes to jade templating, but by looking at the documentation and fiddling around with your example i came up with this [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwWBEo). Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: hey @DavidDomain if you put this is as an answer, I'll mark it correct. you did a little too much, but I was able to figure it out based off of your codepen. so thanks! (here is how you can simplify what you did, http://codepen.io/jaruesink/pen/eprVwM)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I've added this as an answer for others having a similar problem with mixins using jade templates.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the jade documentation my suggestion was to do the following to get rid of the
***Illegal Token Error***, which was actually a bit over exaggerated.

```
- var name = ""
mixin input_mixin(name, name)
  input(name=name)&attributes(attributes)= name

mixin name_of_mixin(type)
    if type == 'multiple'
        - name = '{{:#index}}'
    else if type == 'old'
        - name = 'old'
    else
        - name = 'normal'
+name_of_mixin('foo')
+input_mixin(- name, name)(placeholder='plaeceholder value')
```

[*jaruesink*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778133/jaruesink) came up with the following simplified solution which seems to work just fine. I guess the main problems were the indentation of the mixin-call and the hyphens in front of the conditional statements.

```
- var name = ""
mixin input_mixin(name)
  input(name=name)&attributes(attributes)

mixin name_of_mixin(type)
    if type == 'multiple'
        - name = '{{:#index}}'
    else if type == 'old'
        - name = 'old'
    else
        - name = 'normal'
+name_of_mixin('foo')
+input_mixin(name)(placeholder='placeholder value')
```